# C# PrintCapabilities check whether ISOA4 page media size is supported by printer

Tags: c#, linq, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5, printdialog

I have a PrintCapabilities object and now I am trying to check if the printer supports ISOA4 page media size so that I can iterate over the readonly `enumeration`:

```
PrintDialog print = new PrintDialog();
PrintCapabilities pc = print.PrintQueue.GetPrintCapabilities(print.PrintTicket);

foreach (PageMediaSize mediaSize in pc.PageMediaSizeCapability)
{
    if (mediaSize.PageMediaSizeName == PageMediaSizeName.ISOA4)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A4 size is supported");
        break;
    }
}
```

I am trying to do the same using Linq without success. Is it possible? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this (sorry - I haven't tested this code).

```
if (pc.PageMediaSizeCapability.Any(ms=>ms.PageMediaSizeName == PageMediasizeName.ISOA4))
{
    Console.WriteLine("A4 size is supported");
}
```